# How do I conditionally redirect output to a file, depending on whether some script argument exists?

Tags: bash

I have a script which I would like to use to process some data and input it into a chosen file.

```
(do some stuff)>$(hostname)_$1
```

This works fine if my argument is a file name, but what should I pass (or how should I change the script) if I want to output to the terminal, i.e. stdout?

Comment: `(do some stuff) > /dev/stdout` Or just `(do some stuff)`

Comment: /dev/stdout might work. The latter defeats the notion of passing the input as a parameter to the script.

Comment: @anubhava or even just `do some stuff` to avoid the unnecessary subshell...

Comment: /dev/tty usually names the terminal in unix-like operating systems. /dev/fd/1 and /proc/self/fd/1 are also some aliases for standard output, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer assumes that the question is:

> How do I conditionally redirect output to a file, depending on whether some script argument exists?

In other words, how to reduce duplication in a bash function like this:

```
do_it() {
  if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
      some very
      complicated
      commands
  else
      { some very
        complicated
        commands
      } > "$(logdir)/$1"
  fi
}
```

If that were the question, a simple solution is to conditionally redirect stdout inside a subshell:

```
do_it() {
  (
    if [[ -n $1 ]]; then exec > "$(logdir)/$1"; fi
    some very
    complicated
    commands
  )
}
```

The subshell (created with the parentheses) is necessary in order to limit the effect of the `exec` command to the scope of the function; otherwise, the redirect would continue when the function returned.

Comment: That is a better way of writing my question, to be sure. What are -z and -n?

Comment: @danielb: unary operators which succeed if their argument is zero-length / nonzero length, respectively. See `help test`

Comment: @danielb: Exactly. For the duration of the (sub)shell.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me. If `DUMP_FILE` is empty things go to stdout otherwise to the file. It does the job without using explicit redirection, but just uses pipes and existing applications.

```
function stdout_or_file
{
    local DUMP_FILE=${1:-}

    if [ -z "${DUMP_FILE}" ]; then
        cat
    else
        sed -n "w ${DUMP_FILE}"
    fi
}

function foo()
{
    local MSG=$1
    echo "info: ${MSG}"
}

foo "bar" | stdout_or_file ${DUMP_FILE}
```

Of course, you can squeeze this also in one line

```
foo "bar" | if [ -z "${DUMP_FILE}" ]; then cat; else sed -n "w ${DUMP_FILE}"; fi
```

Besides `sed -n "w ${DUMP_FILE}"` another command that does the same is `dd status=none of=${DUMP_FILE}`